# How to to plot TWO log plots in same figure

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to take two log plots and compare one overlaid on the other.  For linear plots, I can use 
     figure;
     Hold on;
     plot(first)
     plot(second)
and they are plotted one over the other. (As expected)

BUT, if I use a log plot, say for a BODE plot, when I use the "Hold on" command, it changes the x-axis to linear and I lose the log scale on the x-axis.
Example Code below

```
figure;
hold on;
semilogx(omega,20*log10(abs(c_Hs)),'r');  % transfer function #1
semilogx(omega,20*log10(abs(c_HsR)),'b');  % Transfer function #2
```

so HOW do i prevent "hold on" from changing the log scale to linear ???

Answer (score 1):

Place the `hold on;` expression after the first `semilogx` call

```
figure;
semilogx(omega,20*log10(abs(c_Hs)),'r');  % transfer function #1
hold on;
semilogx(omega,20*log10(abs(c_HsR)),'b');  % Transfer function #
```

Or pass both sets of data to the plotting function:

```
figure;
semilogx(omega,20*log10(abs(c_Hs)),'r',omega,20*log10(abs(c_HsR)),'b');
```